# Drag images from browser and drop it into Finder

Tags: finder, graphics, web-browser

Until recently, I was able to drag pictures displayed in my browser to drop them into Finder (Desktop or directory). It doesn't work anymore.

Any idea why ?

NB: Running 10.9.1, happens with Chrome,Safari & Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a reboot everything works fine again. Finder was probably bugging (again ...).

Answer (score 0):

I do this all the time .. but have noticed recently that it takes a bit longer for the cursor to grab the photo or graphic on some sites.

In Safari, using Open Image In New Tab from the contextual menu will give you an even easier drag from that tab, the actual link to the photo ... and it's size!

Comment: I has nothing to do with the website nor the browser. It's the Finder that doesn't seems to take drop inputs.

Comment: It should. It does and it will. Do you have something running like, say, Hazel, or Desktop Utility?